# My CustomAction to run an executable via WixShellExect is failing

Tags: wix, custom-action

I have built a wix but I am falling down at the last part where I run an application that allows users to communicate with the Windows Service I just installed.
The install rolls back.

If I don't include the WixShellExec Custom Action then the exe installs and I can run the application from the install folder with no problem.

I have this in the Product.wxs file:

```
<!--Used to start the Console when install complete-->
<Component Id="Cmp_ArduinoControllerConsole" Directory="dir_Console" Guid="83D1FD64-0DE5-461B-997D-641C394999F1">
<File Id="File_ArduinoControllerConsole" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.MyDir)\Console\RJB.ArduinoController.Console.exe" />
</Component>

<!--Set up the action to run the console at the end of the installation -->
<Property Id="WixShellExecTarget" Value="[#File_ArduinoControllerConsole]" />
<CustomAction Id="Run_File_ArduinoControllerConsole" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="WixShellExec" Impersonate="yes" />

<!--Sets when in the install sequence the Custom Action runs-->
<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="Run_File_ArduinoControllerConsole" 
            Before="InstallFinalize" />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

I get an error in the Installation log:

```
MSI (s) (0C:34) [23:40:29:636]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Windows\Installer\MSI6179.tmp, Entrypoint: WixShellExec

WixShellExec:  Error 0x80070002: ShellExec failed with return code 2
WixShellExec:  Error 0x80070002: failed to launch target

CustomAction Run_File_ArduinoControllerConsole returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
Action ended 23:40:29: Run_File_ArduinoControllerConsole. Return value 3.
```

Can anyone suggest what I've done wrong?

Comment: This might be helpful for this kind of issue http://stackoverflow.com/a/37194792/967180

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution.

I could not get the value in Property:

to produce a value so I changed the Custom action to this:

```
<CustomAction Id='Launch_ArduinoControllerConsole' FileKey='File_ArduinoControllerConsole' ExeCommand='' Return='asyncNoWait' />
```

and replaced it in this:

```
    <InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action='Launch_ArduinoControllerConsole' After='InstallFinalize'>NOT Installed</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Which ran the executable after the install finished.  The CustomAction setting Return='asyncNoWait' is the one to get right.

If anyone finds out why the value in Property is wrong I'm intrigued to know but for now I have a fix.

Answer (score 3):

To access files after they're installed, custom actions must run in deferred context. Set @Execute="deferred" on your CustomAction element. Or, use the technique described in [How To: Run the Installed Application After Setup](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/run_program_after_install.htm).

Comment: Thanks, thi moved me on somewhat.  Now I'm getting:
WixShellError: Error 0x80070057: Failed to get formatted value for property: 'WixShellExecTarget' with value''
So it looks like the value is incorrect.  I'm using the File ID from the component.  I tried using the Component ID but got the same error.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to run the app before InstallFinalize? If it shows UI, you must run it after InstallFinalize and then you won't have either of the problems you've run into.

Comment: I tried marking it with After="InstallFinalize" but I got this erroe:

Run_File_ArduinoControllerConsole is a in-script custom action.  
It must be sequenced in between the InstallInitialize action 
and the InstallFinalize action in the InstallExecuteSequence

I don't mind when it runs as long as the exe is there.

It's an icon that shows in the taskbar with menu items to control the service that the wix installs

Comment: In that case, I recommend using the technique described in the WiX doc: http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/run_program_after_install.htm

Comment: Yes I've been using that as the basis for the above code. Unfortunately that sample requires user interaction to decide if the app should run and I can't have them doing that. Anyway that still wouldn't solve the problem of why the Value in Property is not being parsed correctly. What should the Value be?  What is it supposed to represent?  A path ?  A File ID?

Comment: I fixed it by using a different CustomAction.  See my original post

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, this is how I had to set the value of a Property that was used by an immediate action:

```
<Property Id="MyProperty"> 1234 </Property>
```